# tuneLength argument with search = 'random' option in caret not working

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, grid-search, hyperparameters

I am trying to tune a model via `caret::train` using a random grid search, but I have problems in setting how many grid points to use.

To set the number of sampled random grid points the `caret` doc says to use the `tuneLength` parameter inside the `train` function, but from the trials I have made it seems that the train is always performed on *all grid points*, independently of the value of `tuneLength`. *De facto*, the result is exactly equivalent to do a full scan search.

Here follows a working example.

Create a synthetic dataset, with a `Class` target 2-factor column.

```
require(caret)
require(xgboost)

set.seed(1234)
dt <- twoClassSim(n = 1000)
```

build a grid for an `xgboost` model tuning

```
grid <- expand.grid(
  nrounds = seq(10, 100, by = 10),
  max_depth = c(1, 5, 10),
  gamma = c(0, 1, 2),
  eta = .01,
  subsample = 1,
  colsample_bytree = 1,
  min_child_weight = 1
)
```

This is a 90-point grid.

set a cross-validation resampling and put the random grid search option

```
tc <- trainControl(
  method = 'cv',
  number = 5,
  search = 'random'
)
```

then fit the model with the `tuneLength` option equal to 2.

```
fit <- train(x = dt[, setdiff(names(dt),'Class')], y = dt$Class,
             method = 'xgbTree',
             trControl = tc,
             tuneGrid = grid, tuneLength = 2)
```

I expected to get in the results only 2 grid points evaluation, but instead I get 90 of them, i.e. the tuning is done on *all the grid points*, just as a full grid scan.

And this is not a problem of `xgboost`, since the same thing happens, e.g., with `svmRadial`.

Comment: To be honest, I have never seen `tuneGrid` and `tuneLength` used together; and although the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/4.47/topics/train) does not seem to explicitly forbid this, it would seem that indeed it is not a valid combination. Check also the working example in the docs for [random search.](http://topepo.github.io/caret/random-hyperparameter-search.html), where again `tuneLength` alone is used.

Comment: If you don't set the grid, how does caret choose the points to sample from?

Comment: I guess it goes for a search among some "default" values specific for each algorithm & parameter, but to be honest, I don't know and have never used it myself.

Comment: @desertnaut `getModelInfo('xgbTree')$xgbTree$grid` to output the default grid construction.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53716810/how-to-random-search-in-a-specified-grid-in-caret-package/53724083#53724083) seems to be relevant. Each tunable parameter for each algorithm has a specified lower and upper bound within the corresponding caret method. For instance from the [glmnet](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/models/files/glmnet.R) method you can see `alpha = runif(len, min = 0, 1)` and `lambda = 2^runif(len, min = -10, 3)` where `len` is the `tuneLength`. [Here](https://github.com/topepo/caret/tree/master/models/files) is a link to all models incorporated.

Comment: Not really related to the question but a nice [read](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-win-a-drone-in-20-lines-of-r-code/) regarding tuning.