Random hyperparameter search in r-caret with fixed parameters
I would like to perform a random hyperparameter search with R pacakage caret.
As a solver I use XGBtree.
Since I consider a random forest problem, I would like to have ntree=1 and eta=1 in all tries.
The other parameters ( max_depth, gamma, colsample_bytree, min_child_weight, subsample) should be randomly determined
Is there any way of doing this?
I tried this:
tune_control_random <- caret::trainControl(
   method = "cv", # cross-validation
   number = 5, # with n folds
   verboseIter = FALSE, # no training log
   search="random",
   allowParallel = TRUE # FALSE for reproducible results
 )

 xgb_tune_random <- function(Tune_Grid){
   tt<-caret::train(
   x = x,
   y = as.factor(y),
   num_parallel_tree = 500,
   trControl = tune_control_random,
   tuneGrid = Tune_Grid,
   method = "xgbTree",
   tuneLenght=2,
   verbose = TRUE)
   return(tt)
}


 random_grid <- expand.grid(
   nrounds = 1,
   eta = 1
 )

XGModel.random<-xgb_tune_random(random_grid)


But then I got an error saying that all parameter should be specified.
Thank you for your help in advance!

After some search, I found a useful solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53716810/how-to-random-search-in-a-specified-grid-in-caret-package
